# Undefined variable: mysql whereNotIn

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $screening = Screnning::findOrFail($id);


    $seats = DB::table('seats')->whereNotIn('id',function($q){

        $q->select('seat_id')->from('reservations')
           ->where('screening_id',$screening) ;
          })->get();


    return view('reservation.show',compact('screening','seats'));

}
```

This is the code an I got got the Undefined variable:screening. I guess the problem is the  $screening is inside in the other function.
How can I solve that?

Comment: You should look into using relationship queries.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the variable available in your Closure with `use`:

```
$seats = DB::table('seats')->whereNotIn('id', function($q) use ($screening) {
    $q->select('seat_id')->from('reservations')
       ->where('screening_id', $screening->id);
})->get();
```

More on anonymous functions / Closures: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php - especially interesting for you is "*Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope*"

Comment: `$screening` looks to be a model though, probably want `$screening->id`.